# How do you run a MySQL query from a rake task?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm working on removing duplicates from a legacy database for a client of mine, and I've found a MySQL query to do just that. I want to create a Rake task to run the query for the production server. How would I do that?

MySQL query:

```
    select * from community_event_users;
    create table dups as
      select distinct username, count(*)
      from community_event_users group by username
      having count(*) > 1;
    delete community_event_users from community_event_users inner join dups
    on community_event_users.username = dups.username;

    insert into community_event_users select username from dups;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are on Rails and using ActiveRecord you can simply use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.execute(my_sql)

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(my_sql)
```

Where my_sql is your SQL string.

Comment: I think you need to make sure to call the environment still with the => too.

Comment: This is on Rails 2.3.8; When I run the rake task with `Activerecord::Base.execute(my_sql)`, I get an undefined method error for the execute command.

Comment: how are you calling your rake task? How is that defined? Does that include the :environment task?

Comment: I'm calling it through the terminal; `rake db:duplicates` and yes, it does include the :environment task. `task :duplicates => :environment do`

Comment: is the task in RAILS_ROOT/lib/tasks? Can you see it running rake -T db? Perhaps: http://pastie.org/2232527

Comment: The task is in RAIL_ROOT/lib/tasks. I can see it using the -T command. I tried the code you suggested and it still gives me the undefined method error for execute.

Comment: ah I see, 2.3.8, try running ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

Comment: Thank you! The `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` worked.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5 and above you better use:

```
ApplicationRecord.connection.execute <<~END_OF_SQL
  YOUR QUERY HERE
END_OF_SQL
```